# Do marker animations exist in googlemaps on android?

Tags: android, google-maps, animation

I am trying to create the "falling pins" effect with my app. I have an array of points (longitude and latitude) but I don't know how to make them fall onto the map.

In javascript googlemaps has the animate function but I cannot find a similar function for android. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Create animation on your own :D

Comment: have you heard of someone writing it already? it seems like a common animation that a lot of people would use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom [Overlay](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html).

Comment: Wow, how disappointing. Have you heard of anyone doing something similar?